# Ionic 4 - Unhandled Promise rejection: Error Status 404: App not found

Tags: cordova, ionic4

I'm not sure what's causing this error that appears whenever I initially launch my Ionic 4 chat app.

```js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
polyfills.js:3040 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error Status 404: App not found ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Error Status 404: App not found
    at IonicDeployImpl.<anonymous> (/plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic/dist/common.js:291)
    at step (/plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic/dist/common.js:37)
    at Object.next (/plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic/dist/common.js:18)
    at fulfilled (/plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic/dist/common.js:9)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills.js:2749)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (polyfills.js:2508)
    at polyfills.js:3247
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:2781)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (polyfills.js:2553)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills.js:2959) Error: Error Status 404: App not found
    at IonicDeployImpl.<anonymous> (http://localhost/plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic/dist/common.js:291:35)
    at step (http://localhost/plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic/dist/common.js:37:23)
    at Object.next (http://localhost/plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic/dist/common.js:18:53)
    at fulfilled (http://localhost/plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic/dist/common.js:9:58)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost/polyfills.js:2749:26)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (http://localhost/polyfills.js:2508:43)
    at http://localhost/polyfills.js:3247:34
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost/polyfills.js:2781:31)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost/polyfills.js:2553:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost/polyfills.js:2959:35)
```

I've searched for similar error but none are pertaining to Ionic 4.  The app works without issues so I'm not sure what's causing this.  There is one problem, I'm trying to push notification so when the data is tapped it will navigate to the chat page.  That part isn't working and I'm thinking this may be the cause.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this recently after upgrading to Ionic 5. I solved it by following few steps -

1. Setup the [cordova-plugin-ionic](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic) according to the documentation. For example,

The updated package.json look like -

```
      "cordova-plugin-ionic": {
        "APP_ID": "cabbdf31",
        "CHANNEL_NAME": "Master",
        "UPDATE_METHOD": "background",
        "MAX_STORE": "2",
        "MIN_BACKGROUND_DURATION": "30",
        "UPDATE_API": "https://api.ionicjs.com"
      },
```

An then added `<preference name="DisableDeploy" value="true" />` to config.xml.

2. I also installed the latest CL and configured it to use 'pro'.

```
npm i -g @ionic/cli

ionic config set backend pro -g
```